# Reading token from AsyncStorage before a fetch call

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, asyncstorage

In my `ReactNative` app, I'm trying to come up with a nice pattern to read the `access_token` I store in `AsyncStorage` and use it in a `fetch` call.

In other words, I want to create a pattern that uses some type of wrapper that makes sure that the `fetch` call always has the `access_token` it needs. So execution order should always be:

> Invoke Fetch Call -> Get Token from AsyncStorage and Prep Header -> Execute Fetch Call

I came up with the following code but it looks like I'm having problems with the `Async` part of `AsyncStorage` and my `fetch` calls are going out without the token.

Here's my `fetch` call:

```
export const someApiCall = (request) => {

   const url = 'https://myapi.com/add';

   return (dispatch) => fetch(url, fetchOptionsPost(request))
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {

                // Got data. Dispatch some action

            }
        })
}
```

Here, I'm using a helper function to prepare the headers, etc. Here's what the `fetchOptionsPost()` looks like:

```
export const fetchOptionsPost = (request) => {

    getAccessToken()
        .then(token => {

            return {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(request)
            }
       });
};
```

And the `getAccessToken()` function simply reads it from `AsyncStorage` as below:

```
export const getAccessToken = async () => {

    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
}
```

This pattern is NOT working and API calls are going out without a token.

I also want to mention that if I hard-code the token inside my `fetchOptionsPost()` method, everything works fine. Clearly, the issue here is that the `fetchOptionsPost()` is not returning anything.

What can I do to make sure that I will ALWAYS have my token in my `fetchOptionsPost`?

Comment: Are you adding access token into AsyncStorage? If so, where are you setting?

Comment: I do have a separate function that handles saving the token. I checked to make sure the token is stored so there's no problem there. The issue seems to be with code flow. JavaScript simply isn't waiting till the token is retrieved before it executes the `fetch` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with which seems to work fine. I still would appreciate any suggestions or improvements to this code.

First, here's what my `fetch` call looks like now. I wrapped it inside the `getAccessToken()` function which is an `async` call but because I'm using `redux-thunk`, I'm able to do this.

```
export const someApiCall = (request) => {

   const url = 'https://myapi.com/add';

   return (dispatch) => getAccessToken()
        .then(token => {
            fetch(url, fetchOptionsPost(request, token))
                .then((response) => {

                     if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {

                          // Got data. Dispatch some action

                      }
                 })
        })
}
```

I slightly changed my `fetchOptionsPost()` helper function which now accepts the token. It's also a bit more robust now. If it doesn't get a token, it simply omits the `Authorization` part in the header. I opted for this approach as some calls to my API backend do not require authentication. Also the `isValidString()` is another helper validation function I created to make sure I do get a valid string. It returns a `TRUE` or `FALSE` response based on the string value inputed:

```
export const fetchOptionsPost = (data, token = null) => {

    if (isValidString(token)) {

        return {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    } else {

        return {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    }
};
```

And finally, the `getAccessToken()` function which didn't really change but here it is:

```
export const getAccessToken = async () => {

    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
}
```

As I said, I'd appreciate any comments or suggestions on further improving this code.

Hope this is useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

you could add `token` call inside `someApiCall` function .And also create the options on inside the function . function was async so fetch only run after get token result

**Updated**

```
const fetchOptionsPost = (token) =>{
  return ({
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
  })
}

export const someApiCall = async(request) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
  const url = 'https://myapi.com/add';

  fetch(url, fetchOptionsPost(token))
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
       // call the dispatch here
      })
}
```

**Why use async inside on main function**

`AsyncStorage` only have async callback. if you are set the AsyncStorage as separate function you should call async for the both function.Thats why i added with in parent async function and pass the token to `fetchOptionsPost`

Comment: Then I'd have to repeat this code in every `fetch` call. In order to streamline my API calls, I created the `fetchOptionsPost()` function.

Comment: I think I tried this but it didn't work. Let me try it again.

Comment: This gives me an error that reads: "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Comment: i think you are using redux. for redux async call https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk . check the code sandbox its working  with token https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lake-d9wxs

Comment: Yes, I do use both Redux and Redux Thunk. Let me study your code. Seems pretty similar to what I was doing.

Comment: But you didn't use `dispatch` in the `fetch` call which is why your async fetch call is working. Once I get a response in my fetch call, I `dispatch` actions to commit the data I received into my Redux store. Once you involve `dispatch`, it doesn't like promises. It wants simple objects.

Comment: please check the update answer .i dont know the redux fully . as per documentation https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition .All are called dispatch inside callback of fetch . let try it like

Answer (score 0):

Use Async and await method and get the token before each call.

```
async ()=>{
let token =await getTokenFromLocal();
return (dispatch) => fetch(url, fetchOptionsPost(request))
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {

                // Got data. Dispatch some action

            }
        })
}
```